# Creating emotional text-based artwork using Sent2Vec and POSTagging?

Tags: nlp

I want to create computer-generated abstract based on the following criteria:

Nouns and verbs will correspond to round or jagged shapes. Lets say 0 is very jagged and 10 is very round. The rounder something is, the more calm or serene. The more jagged, the angrier or excited it is. Each word can get assigned a "weight" from 0-10 based on its perceived emotional content.

Adjectives and adverbs will correspond to warm or cool colors. Colors like blue and purple will correspond to calmness or serenity, red and orange to anger, yellow to happiness, etc. Same weight rules apply.

I'm not very experienced with Artificial Neural Networks or NLP and I want to make something like this based on any text input. How should I approach this? Could it simply do POS tagging on the entire document and parse it through Sent2Vec?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a unusual NLP use, however you could try the following:

1. Define a set of words and attribute them values.
2. Use NLP to automactically extract POS from text.
3. Using the previous steps, build your art with the extracted features by writing an algorithm.

No need for vectorization (this is only useful for machine learning algorithms) or any Sentiment Analysis approach (this is when you have a machine learning problem).